# can't see the html code that respone from server using ajax and php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

**1.Jquery Script with Ajax**

```
$('#location').change(function(){
    var l = $('#location :selected').val();
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
        url : 'function/get_location.php',
        dataType:'html',
        data : { loc : l},
        success: function(data){
            $('#advertise_record').html(data);
        }   
    });
});
```

i want to see the html code the response from server displayed in a blog div called #advertise_record in my web page . but when right clicked view source code i didn't see that html code inside that blog but the result of it show here.

**2.html code**

```
<div id="advertise_record"></div>
```

i need the result that response from server display here.
it's show the result but when i right click view source code i didn't see that code.

**3. get_location.php**

```
<?php

    include_once (dirname(__FILE__). '/dbconfig.php');

    define('ADVERTISE_DIRECTORY','../advertise/');

    if(isset($_POST['loc'])) $loc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['loc']);

    switch($loc){
        case 0 : $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tblads';break;
        case 1 : $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tblads WHERE loc_id="'.$loc.'"'; break;
        case 2 : $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tblads WHERE loc_id="'.$loc.'"'; break;
        case 3 : $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tblads WHERE loc_id="'.$loc.'"'; break;
        default:"";
    }
    ?>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="850px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="file" name="filename" id="filename" class="text"/></td>
                <td><label class="title">Name :</label><input type="text" name="ads_name" id="ads_name" class="text" style="width:150px;"></td>
                <td><label class="title">URL :</label><input type="text" name="url" id="url" class="text" style="width:150px;"/></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="update" id="update" class="button button_update"/></td>
            </tr>
    <?php
    $output = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($output)){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center">
                <div style="width: 700px;height: auto;overflow-x: scroll;">
                    <img src='<?php echo ADVERTISE_DIRECTORY.$row['image_name']?>' alt='<?php echo $row['ads_name'];?>' />  
                </div>
            </td>
            <td align="center"><a href='#tab-advertise?edit=<?php echo $row['ads_id']?>' >Edit</a></td>
        </tr>   
        <?php
    }
?>  
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

so what's wrong with my code . really thank for you time to answer.

Comment: Why is your MIME type set to `image/jpeg`? If you wan't to output HTML code, then you should either remove the `header()` function, or set it to `text/html`.

Comment: ok ! i removed it , but it still doesn't work.one more i want to display image but the image doesn't show. why . thank for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to see anything in the source that wasn't there initially. If you want to see the html that is returned by your ajax calls check the network/net tab in your browsers development tools. Also you're setting the content type for an image which is incorrect since your output is an html table.

Comment: in this table I want to display image as well you can see my code in get_location.php right ? but the image doesn't show in my web page why ?

Comment: @NoeurPhireak if the images do not show then the paths(i.e. `src` attributes) are wrong.

Comment: Ok ! now i can load image to my page .one more problem is when i right click to view source code i didn't see the html code to display that image in my page. why ? thank you for your time..